# Acessar texto do form usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando colocar o valor do "10" ao valor de uma uma variavel, Você vai conseguir abrir o botão com este código porem o valor 10 (quantidade de produto) porem não esta sendo alterado, se eu simplesmente trocar o 10 por 20, quando abrir o botao vai estar 20 a quantidade, porem quero alterar com o script porque estou criando um sistema que altera os valores dependendo da opção selecionada.

```
<form method="post" target="pagseguro" action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html">  

    <!-- Campos obrigatórios -->  
    <input name="receiverEmail" type="hidden" value="minevillager001@hotmail.com">  
    <input name="currency" type="hidden" value="BRL">  

    <!-- Itens do pagamento (ao menos um item é obrigatório) -->  
    <input name="itemId1" type="hidden" value="001">  
    <input name="itemDescription1" type="hidden" value="EloJob">  
    <input name="itemAmount1" type="hidden" value = "100.00">
    <input name="itemQuantity1" type="hidden" value="10">  
    <input name="itemWeight1" type="hidden" value="0">  

    <!-- Código de referência do pagamento no seu sistema (opcional) -->  
    <input name="reference" type="hidden" value="REF1234">  

    <!-- Dados do comprador (opcionais) -->  
    <input name="senderName" type="hidden" value="José Comprador">  
    <input name="senderAreaCode" type="hidden" value="11">  
    <input name="senderPhone" type="hidden" value="56273440">  
    <input name="senderEmail" type="hidden" value="minevillager001@hotmail.com">  

    <!-- submit do form (obrigatório) -->  
    <input alt="Pague com PagSeguro" name="submit"  type="image" src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/120x53-pagar.gif"/>  

</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var randu = 20.00;
    document.getElementById("10").value = randu;
 </script>
```

Comment: O que queres fazer com `document.getElementById("10").value = randu;`?

Comment: alterar o valor do 10.00 localizado em : `<input name="itemQuantity1" type="hidden" value="10.00">`

Comment: Você apagou a outra pergunta? Quando for assim, basta editar a atual, ao invés de criar outra.

Comment: E queres alterar quando? Porque não colocas esse valor no HTML diretamente? De onde vem `20.00;` em `var randu = 20.00;`? isso é compilado no servidor?

Comment: sim vem de randu = 20.00 editei se voce poder ler novamente nao o codigo o post.

Comment: Já testaste `document.querySelector('input[name="itemQuantity1"]').value = randu;`? Não percebo de onde vem o teu `10` aqui: `getElementById("10")`

Comment: não, vo tentar agora.

Comment: consegui sergiooooooo, Muito obrigado valeu apena esperar 40 minutos depois de vc excluir meu post kkk, e pq nao conseguia posta o codigo, obrigado lucas <3

Comment: aonde coloco como resolvido?

Comment: e aqui:

<script type="text/javascript">
      document.querySelector('input[name="itemAmount1"]').value = 200.00;
  </script>
<!-- This is the script-->

Comment: sabe pq nao ta dando?

Comment: Dei uma resposta, dá uma olhada. Se resolve o teu problema podes marcar como aceite.

Comment: aaa deu sim agr q li eu coloquei 'number' ('20.00')

Comment: tem como eu colocar assim?:

 randu = 20

<script type="text/javascript">
      document.querySelector('input[name="itemAmoun1"]').value = randu+'.00';
  </script>
<!-- This is the script-->

?

Comment: Nesse caso faz assim: `document.querySelector('input[name="itemAmoun1"]').value = randu.toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 4):

Não percebo de onde vem o `"10"` em `document.getElementById("10")`, pois esse método procura elementos com `id="10"`.

Mas uma vez que os inputs têm outros atributos, podes usar por exemplo assim:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="itemQuantity1"]').value = randu;
```

desse modo vais selecionar o primeiro elemento que tiver um atributo `name` com o valor/nome de `itemQuantity1`. E aí podes mudar o seu `.value` para o valor que `randu` tiver.

Repara ainda que `var randu = 20.00;` é o mesmo que `var randu = 20;`. Se queres colocar as casa decimais deves usar uma string: `var randu = '20.00';`. Outra opção seria usar o [`.toFixed(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) que transforma números em strings, com *x* casa decimais, assim:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="itemQuantity1"]').value = randu.toFixed(2);
```